# How can I calculate a confidence interval for true mean of one set being higher than another, based on samples from each?

Tags: confidence-interval, mean

I have two sets A and B each containing N elements and want to show that the true mean of A is less than that of B with certain degree of confidence. (Specifically, the sets represents items of "yes" and "no", and I want to show that one set contain more yeses than the other.) I do not know the true mean of either set. I am trying to do this with the smallest number of samples possible as getting samples in this case is expensive.

How do I calculate the probability that the true mean of A is less than B given a number of samples from each set?

Comment: The technique you want is the standard error of the difference between proportions.

Comment: @rolando2, thank you - is there a wikipedia article or other link that you could post on this subject?

Comment: Are you looking for **(a)** a *confidence interval* for the difference in proportions, or **(b)** a formal hypothesis test of the null that the proportions are equal against one of the alternatives (you pick) **(i)** that underlying ('true') probability of 'yes' in A is $<$ the underlying probability of 'yes' in B;  or **(ii)** as in *(i)* but with $\neq$ rather than $<$?

Comment: @Glen_b, thank you for helping me formalize the question. I would like to disprove that the underlying probability in A < that of B, b.i. in your list.

Comment: If you want to be able to *disprove* b(i) you'll actually want a one tailed null that goes the other way. If the opposite null is untenable, you're left with the direction you want.

Comment: @Glen_b, as I can feely choose which which sets to actually use for A and B, I'd be happy as long as I can do either direction :)